# How to derive the following identity?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

The book [Irresistible Integrals by George Boros and Victor Moll](http://books.google.com/books?id=g9tH8M3NvDIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=irresistible+integrals&hl=pt-PT&ei=W8sATYbBLoSXOu2craYB&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page 204 has the following identity

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+x}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{k+x+1}{k+x} \times \frac{k}{k+1}\right)$

How does one derive this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multiply out

$$\prod_{k=1}^N\left(\frac{k+x+1}{k+x} \times \frac{k}{k+1}\right)$$

and cancel like terms. You will be left with

$$\frac{1}{1+x}\left(\frac{N+x+1}{N+1}\right) .$$

Comment: Assuming $x$ is an integer?

Comment: @Alex: The terms cancel whether or not $x$ is integer.

Comment: Sorry, I was being dense.

Comment: @Alex, Are you from future? why everything is dense in future?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $ $ It *telescopes* $\, \rm\displaystyle \prod_{k\:=\:a}^{b} \frac{f(k\!+\!1)}{f(k)}\,  =   \ \frac{\color{green}{\rlap{---}f(a\!+\!1)}}{\color{#C00}{f(a)}}\frac{\color{royalblue}{\rlap{---}f(a\!+\!2)}}{\color{green}{\rlap{---}f(a\!+\!1)}}\frac{\phantom{\rlap{--}f(3)}}{\color{royalblue}{\rlap{---}f(a\!+\!2)}}\, \cdots\,  \frac{\color{brown}{\rlap{--}f(b)}}{\phantom{\rlap{--}f(b)}}\frac{f(b\!+\!1)}{\color{brown}{\rlap{--}f(b)}} =\,  \frac{f(b\!+\!1)}{\color{#c00}{f(a)}} $

Apply that to both factors in the product then take the limit as $\rm\ b\to\infty\:.$

For some other examples of additive/multiplicative telescopy see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/proof-of-inequalities-by-induction/6586#6586) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/summation-of-sum-limits-n1-infty-fracxx1-cdots-xn-1yy1-cdo/7453#7453) or [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6805/simple-proof-by-induction-9-divides-n3-n13-n23/6814#6814)