# Infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{1+\pi^{2^{-n}}}$ calculation problem

Tags: infinite-product

To calculate the infinite product $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{1+\pi^{\frac{1}{2^n}}},$$ I found that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+\pi^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}\right)$ converges, so as $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{1+\pi^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}.$

The task though is asking to calculate the product  and not just verify the convergence. Is there a mathematical way to calculate this product, or calculate this limit : $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^n}{\left(1+\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\left(1+\pi^{\frac{1}{2^2}}\right)\cdots\left(1+\pi^{\frac{1}{2^n}}\right)}$$

Thank you for your time

Comment: Multiply both numerator and denominator by $\left(\pi^{\frac{1}{2^n}}-1\right)$; that's going to simplify things a great deal.

Comment: See the second half of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1829775/269624)

Comment: @You'reInMyEye oh didn't realized it. Sorry