# A curious limit for $-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, pi

How to prove this ?
$$-\frac\pi2 = \lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)! \ln 2n}$$

Comment: I tried to typeset your equation more nicely. Please check if I did right.

Comment: Personally, I'd put the $(-1)^n$ in the numerator.

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: You have to pick an infinity, I think: $x\to +\infty$ or $x\to -\infty$.  Might seem pedantic, but $x\to\infty$ means something specific. (We often write $n\to\infty$, but there, $n$ is usually a natural number, and there is only "one" infinity it can go to.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: it looks rather straightforward to guess which infinity mick has in mind...

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here, the expression $\,u\to\infty\,$ is *always* understood as "$\,u\,$ going to (plus) infinity", otherwise it must specifically be added a minus sign: $\,x\to -\infty\,$

Comment: @Fabian Yes, as I said, it may seem pedantic, but it is important to get used to making clear distinctions when talking about limits. Not knowing OP, but based on the original posting formatting, I assumed he was inexperienced, and therefore would be helped by reminding him of the distinction.

Comment: The source is me.
In the original i typed +oo. I believe -oo would give + $\pi/2$ btw. ( its been a long long time since i came up with this lim )
Thanks for the Tex edit.
I prefer the (-1) above too.

Comment: lol its trivial that -oo gives the same result times -1. :)

Comment: @mick Do you remember in what context you came up with this limit? This could help us figure out what tools could be relevant in finding the limit.

Comment: As often when you see x^a/log(x)^b its related to number theory. Although i did not give it that tag. It appeared to me in an attempt to prove the prime twins conjecture. It reappeared when trying to prove RH. ( related to spacing of zero's ).

Comment: Numerically [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%28-1%29%5En+%5Cfrac%7B%2810%29%5E%7B2n-1%7D%7D%7B%282n%29%21+%5Cln+2n%7D) seems to confirm that the limit is indeed $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  The question is how to deal with the logarithm on the bottom.

Comment: Your question is the same as trying to show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)\left(2n\right)!\log(2n)}dx=\frac{-\pi}{2} $$ I am not sure how to do this, but I have seen similar integrals such as $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n-2}}{(2n-1)!}dx=-\frac{\pi}{2} $$ which follows from basic complex analysis.  Could you elaborate more on where this integral came from?

Comment: Surprisingly the formula is also in http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=743 dated 7.Aug.2012 but was not discussed there.

Comment: Not a surprise. I asked permission to post it here. Do I need to give credit to others in my questions ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using 
$$\int_0^\infty \left(2 n\right)^{-t} \mathrm{d} t = \frac{1}{\ln(2n)}$$
the sum becomes
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)! \cdot \ln(2n)} = \int_0^\infty \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)! \cdot (2n)^t} \right)\mathrm{d}t
$$
Now, further using 
$$
   \int_0^\infty u^{t-1} \mathrm{e}^{-2 n u} \mathrm{d} u = \Gamma(t) (2n)^{-t}
$$
we rewrite the sum as a double integral:
$$
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)! \cdot \ln(2n)} = \int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^\infty  \frac{u^{t-1}}{\Gamma(t)}\mathrm{d}t \right)  \frac{\cos\left(x \mathrm{e}^{-u}\right)-1}{x} \mathrm{d} u 
$$
In the large $x$ limit, the main contribution to the integral comes from large $u$. For large $u$, 
$$
    \int_0^\infty  \frac{u^{t-1}}{\Gamma(t)}\mathrm{d}t \approx \sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{u^{t-1}}{\Gamma(t)} = \mathrm{e}^{u}
$$
[image]

Thus:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)! \cdot \ln(2n)} &=& \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{u} \frac{\cos\left(x \mathrm{e}^{-u}\right)-1}{x} \mathrm{d} u = \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^\infty \frac{\cos\left(x/w\right)-1}{x} \mathrm{d} w \\
  &=& \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{1/x}^\infty \left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{v}\right)-1\right) \mathrm{d} v = \int_{0}^\infty \left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{v}\right)-1\right) \mathrm{d} v \\
  &=& -\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Euh i did not get all those steps.
It would be helpful if you explained what substitutions or partials you used. Also a plot is not a proof although i guess you know that and its not crucial to the proof.

Comment: Masterful, +1   .

Comment: @mick Sorry for being sketchy. Large $u$ behavior of $\int_0^\infty \frac{u^{t-1}}{\Gamma(t)} \mathrm{d} t$ can also be obtained using [Laplace's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method). I used [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). Could you please tell me more precisely which steps you did not get. Those at the end of the post, or some others?

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for the upvote and for your kind words.

Comment: @ Sahsha I feel silly for not understanding , but you already lost me at the double integral. blush

Comment: $$ \int_0^\infty \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} \frac{1}{(2n)^t} \right) \mathrm{d} t = \int_0^\infty \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} \frac{1}{\Gamma(t)} \int_0^\infty u^{t-1} \mathrm{e}^{-2n u} \mathrm{d} u \right) \mathrm{d} t = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{u^{t-1}}{\Gamma(t)} \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} \mathrm{e}^{-2n u} \right) \mathrm{d} u \mathrm{d} t $$ The latter sum evaluates to $\frac{\cos(x \mathrm{e}^{-u})-1}{x}$.

Comment: Thanks. Off course. Excellent use of the gamma function.

Comment: @Mick This trick of summation by integral representation can be (partially) automated, esp. using multimensional residues - see [my post here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3720/242)

Comment: Nice proof! (+1)

Comment: uh, i missed this gem (+1)