# $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)! \ln 2n}$ is totally monotone?

Tags: calculus, monotone-functions

I think

$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)! \ln 2n}$ is totally monotone.

Bernstein's theorem and his integral transform convinced me.

Am I correct ?

Probably related or useful is a function like

$f(x,k) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n)! \ln (2n+k)}$

which follows or almost follows from differentiating.

This is a follow-up of the question

[A curious limit for $-\frac{\pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191008/a-curious-limit-for-frac-pi2)

about the same function.

Comment: What is the definition of totally monotone?

Comment: @A.P. See the wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions

so basically for $ x> 0$ the derivatives alternate in sign.

Comment: this is also called completely monotonic and the book by Widder on Laplace transform has a lot about them