# A gamma function inequality

Tags: inequality, special-functions, gamma-function

I would like to prove $$\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(n+1)} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ for all natural $n \ge 1$. The inequality does seem to be true numerically, but the proof eludes me.

Comment: [Stirling](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html) would be of great service...

Comment: Have you tried a proof by induction?  Do you know the value of $\Gamma(\pi)$?

Comment: @cch: Yes, and yes.

Comment: On reconsideration: Yes, and no.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9372/why-doesnt-this-series-converge/9379#9379

Comment: Sorry -- I meant to type $\Gamma(1/2)$ above -- you would need that for an induction proof.

Comment: @J. M.: Maybe looking at some specific proof of Stirling's formula would help - but to me that is an asymptotic formula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This follows directly from [Gautschi's inequality](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6.E4), valid for $0 < s < 1$ and $x > 0$:

$$x^{1-s} < \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+s)} < (x+1)^{1-s}.$$

As a side note, the link is to NIST's new (as of this year) [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/).  The DLMF is an update of the classic Abramowitz and Stegun text, *[Handbook of Mathematical Functions](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/)*.

Comment: Mike, I hope you don't mind if I changed the link to link directly to the formula. In any event, DLMF gives [this](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0103289) as the reference for Gautschi's inequality; sadly there seems to be no digital archive for the *Journal of Mathematics and Physics*.

Comment: @J.M.: That's fine.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a direct proof:

The gamma function satisfies $\Gamma(n+1) = n \Gamma(n)$,
so the function $g(x) = \ln \Gamma(x)$ satisfies
$g(n+1) = \ln n + g(n)$.
In other words, the line segment between the points $(n,g(n))$
and $(n+1,g(n+1))$ has slope $\ln n$.

Moreover, $g$ is known to be a convex function for $x>0$
(cf. the [Bohr–Mollerup theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem)),
so the point $(n+1/2, g(n+1/2))$ lies *below* that line segment:
$g(n+1/2) < g(n+1) - \frac12 \ln n$.
Exponentiating both sides gives $\Gamma(n+1/2) < \Gamma(n+1) / \sqrt{n}$,
as desired.

Comment: I suspect that Gautschi's inequality is proved in a similar way. Incidentally, $n$ doesn't have to be an integer.

Comment: For a proof that $\Gamma$ is log-convex (using Hölder's inequality), see PlanetMath: http://planetmath.org/?op=getobj&from=objects&id=3808.

Comment: Here is [a proof of the log-convexity of $\Gamma$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/101007/) using Young's Inequality.

Answer (score 7):

For a completely elementary proof let

$$I_n= \int_0^{ \pi/2} \sin^n x \textrm{ d}x $$

then integration by parts gives

$$I_n = \frac{n-1}{n} I_{n-2} . \quad (1) $$

From which we get

$$I_{2n}= \frac{2n-1}{2n} \frac{2n-3}{2n-2} \cdots \frac{1}{2} \frac{\pi}{2}  \quad (2) $$

and

$$I_{2n+1}= \frac{2n}{2n+1} \frac{2n-2}{2n-1} \cdots \frac{2}{3} .  \quad (3) $$

Since $ \sin^{2n+1} x < \sin^{2n} x $ for $ x \in (0,\pi/2) $ we have

$$I_{2n+1}< I_{2n} . \quad (4) $$

Also, from $(1)$ we have $(2n+1)I_{2n+1} = 2nI_{2n-1} > 2nI_{2n}$ since $I_{2n-1} >I_{2n}.$

Therefore using this and $(4)$

$$ \frac{2n+1}{2n} > \frac{ I_{2n} }{ I_{2n+1} } > 1 .  \quad (5) $$

But from $(2)$ and $(3)$

$$  \frac{ I_{2n} }{ I_{2n+1} }  = \frac{2n+1}{2} \frac{ (2n!)^2 }{ 4^{2n} (n!)^4 } \pi .$$

Putting this in $(5)$ gives

$$ \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n} } > \frac{1}{4^n} { 2n \choose n } \sqrt{ \pi } > \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ n + 1/2} }.$$

i.e.

$$ \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n} } > \frac{ \Gamma(n + 1/2) }{ \Gamma(n+1) } > \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ n + 1/2} }.$$

Comment: Tsk, I was expecting that it would be Moron who would post this proof... :D

Comment: @J.M. Yes, one develops a feel for the sort of mathematics that our members enjoy.

Comment: @J.M: Wallis! Wallis! Wallis! :-)

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on Shai Covo's answer:

$$2n\left[{2n\choose n} 4^{-n}\right]^2
= {1\over2}\,{3\over2}\,{3\over4}\,{5\over4}\cdots {{2n-1}\over{2n-2}}\,{{2n-1}\over{2n}}
={1\over 2}\prod_{j=2}^n\left(1+{1\over4j(j-1)}\right).
$$

By Wallis's formula, the middle expression converges to $2\over\pi$.
The right hand expression shows that it is strictly increasing. Therefore, multiplying by $\pi/2$ and taking square roots shows that
$$\sqrt{n\pi}{2n\choose n} 4^{-n}\uparrow 1.$$

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
\Gamma \bigg(n + \frac{1}{2}\bigg) = \frac{{(2n)!}}{{4^n n!}}\sqrt \pi  
$$
(see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)),
we have
$$
\frac{{\Gamma (n + \frac{1}{2})}}{{\Gamma (n+1)}} = \frac{{{2n \choose n}}}{{4^n }}\sqrt \pi  .
$$
This might be very useful, but I have to check.

Comment: Well, at least Byron found this useful...

Comment: Yes, so I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with yet another proof:
**Lemma.** Let $0<\alpha<z$. Then $\Gamma(z)<\sqrt{\Gamma(z-\alpha)\Gamma(z+\alpha)}$.
***Proof***: 
$$
\Gamma(z)=\int_0^{\infty} t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt=\int_0^{\infty} t^{\frac{(z-\alpha)-1}{2}} t^{\frac{(z+\alpha)-1}{2}} e^{-t}dt=\langle\cdot^{\frac{(z-\alpha)-1}{2}},\;\cdot^{\frac{(z+\alpha)-1}{2}} \rangle,\\
$$
where $\langle f,\;g \rangle:=\int_0^{\infty} f(t)g(t)e^{-t}dt$. Now apply Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and since functions $\cdot^{\frac{(z-\alpha)-1}{2}}\;\;\text{and}\;\;\cdot^{\frac{(z+\alpha)-1}{2}}$ are linearly independent, this inequality is strict:
$$
\langle\cdot^{\frac{(z-\alpha)-1}{2}},\;\cdot^{\frac{(z+\alpha)-1}{2}} \rangle<\left(\int_0^{\infty} t^{(z-\alpha)-1} e^{-t}dt\cdot\int_0^{\infty} t^{(z+\alpha)-1} e^{-t}dt\right)^{1/2}=\sqrt{\Gamma(z-\alpha)\Gamma(z+\alpha)}.\;\;\blacksquare
$$
Now take $x>0$ and apply the aforementioned lemma with $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$:
$$
\frac{\Gamma\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(x+1)}<\frac{\sqrt{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(x+1)}}{\Gamma(x+1)}=\sqrt{\frac{\Gamma(x)}{x\Gamma(x)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}.\;\;\;\blacksquare
$$

Answer (score -1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\Gamma(x+1)>\frac{\frac{(900\gamma^2+73\pi^2)x}{900\gamma}+\frac{73}{100}}{\frac{\pi^2 x}{9\gamma}+1}\quad \textbf{[1]}
\end{eqnarray*}
i want to prove this inquality on $(0,1) is increasing 
i defined it as

i defined it as

\begin{eqnarray*}
w(x)=\frac{\log[\Gamma(x+1)(\frac{\pi^2 x}{9\gamma}+1)]}{\log[\frac{(900\gamma^2+73\pi^2)x}{900\gamma}+\frac{73}{100}]} \quad [2]
\end{eqnarray*}
but [2] not increasing to prove it !
what  it need to get it increasing