# Equality with Euler–Mascheroni constant

Tags: calculus, power-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

While trying to prove [$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\log (x)}{e^x+1} \, dx = -\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(2)$ How to show?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100321/integral-with-exponential-function-and-logarithm) in an alternative way, I came to this solution:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\log (k+1)+\gamma }{(k+1)}.$$

As both solutions have to be the same, the following equality should be valid:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\log (k+1)+\gamma }{(k+1)}=- \frac{1}{2}{{\log }^2(2)}. $$

Can anyone give me some advice on how to prove this equality.

p.s. You can be sure that the equality is correct, as I checked it numerically.

Comment: So, obviously the hard part is $\displaystyle \sum_k \frac{(-1)^k\log(k)}{k!}$. I think a possible route would be to see if you can find $\displaystyle \sum_k \frac{(-1)^kk^x}{k!}$ for a general $x$ (it's easy for integral $x$) and then you can differentiate both sides and let $x=0$. I have to run, but that should work, assuming that sum isn't actually too crazy for non-integral $x$.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote this right?  I get
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{\log(k+1)+\gamma}{(k+1)!} = -.1548995048$ and $-\frac{1}{2} \log^2(2) = -.2402265070$ approximately

Comment: The ! should be removed from the denominator:  $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{\log(k+1)+\gamma}{k+1}=-\frac{1}{2}(\log 2)^2.$  This is obtained from the integral by expanding $(1+e^x)^{-1}=e^{-x}-e^{-2x}+{\dots}$ and integrating term-by-term.

Comment: This is really annoying. I removed the !. I am very ver sorry for this error.

Answer (score 8):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\log(k)+\gamma}{k}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log(2k)+\gamma}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log(k)+\gamma}{k}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log(2)+\log(k)+\gamma}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log(k)+\gamma}{k}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), we get that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\log(n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{12n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\tag{2}
$$
and that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(k)}{k}=\frac12\log(n)^2+C+\frac{\log(n)}{2n}-\frac{\log(n)-1}{12n^2}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^4}\right)\tag{3}
$$
Applying $(2)$ and $(3)$ to $(1)$, leaving out the terms which vanish, we get
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\log(k)+\gamma}{k}\\
&=\small{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log(2)(\log(n){+}\gamma)+\left(\frac12\log(n)^2+C+\gamma(\log(n){+}\gamma)\right)-\left(\frac12\log(2n)^2+C+\gamma(\log(2n){+}\gamma)\right)\right)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log(2)(\log(n)+\gamma)-\log(2)\log(n)-\frac12\log(2)^2-\gamma\log(2)\right)\\
&=-\frac12\log(2)^2\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What is C in (3)?

Comment: @wnvl: I don't know if it has a closed form or simple name, but it doesn't matter since it gets canceled.

Comment: @wnvl: The error in $(3)$ turns out to be less than $\dfrac{log(n)}{120n^4}$, so we can compute $C = -0.07281584548367672486$ to $20$ places by setting $n=100000$.

Comment: @wnvl: I ran that constant through the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/index), and it could not find a match. That leads me to think that the constant may not have a closed form or simple name.

Answer (score 6):

This can be solved similarly to the [original problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100321/integral-with-exponential-function-and-logarithm)  The Dirichlet eta function is defined by
$$
\eta(s):=\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}.
$$
The given sum can be rewritten as 
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^n \frac{\log n}{n}+\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^n \frac{\gamma}{n}=
\eta'(1)-\gamma \log 2.\qquad (*)$$ We have
$$
\eta(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^s}-2\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{(2n)^s}=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)
$$
so, using the expansions 
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma+O(s-1),$$ $$
2^{1-s}=e^{(1-s)\log 2}=1-(s-1)\log 2+\frac{1}{2}(\log 2)^2 (s-1)^2+O((s-1)^3),
$$
we get $\eta'(1)=\gamma \log 2 -\frac{1}{2}(\log 2)^2$, so (*) equals $-\frac{1}{2}(\log 2)^2$.

Comment: In fact, I use the result from [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/100975/) to derive the expansion for $\zeta(s)$ you cite above. See [*Riemann zeta near 1*](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/zetanear1.html)

Comment: Great answer but something's off by a sign and I can't figure out what. The term $-\frac{1}{2}(\log 2)^2$ comes from the term $\left ( \zeta'=-\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}\right )* \color{red}{-}(2^{1-s}_{\text{third term}})=\color{red}{+}\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}*\frac{1}{2}(\log 2)^2 (s-1)^2=\frac{1}{2}(\log 2)^2$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is equivalent to showing

$$
\sum_{n\ge1}{(-1)^n\log n\over n}=\gamma\log2+\frac12\log^22
$$

Now, let's first consider the finite case:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\le N}{(-1)^n\log n\over n}
&=2\sum_{n\le N/2}{\log(2n)\over2n}-\sum_{n\le N}{\log n\over n}+\mathcal O\left(\log N\over N\right) \\
&=\sum_{n\le N/2}{\log2+\log n\over n}-\sum_{n\le N}{\log n\over n}+\mathcal O\left(\log N\over N\right) \\
&=\log2\sum_{n\le N/2}\frac1n-\sum_{N/2<n\le N}{\log n\over n}+\mathcal O\left(\log N\over N\right) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

In fact, using Riemann-Stieltjes integral, we can show

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{N/2<n\le N}{\log n\over n}
&=\int_{N/2}^N{\log x\over x}\mathrm d\lfloor x\rfloor \\
&={N\log(N)-N\log(N/2)\over N}-\int_{N/2}^N[x-\{x\}]\mathrm d\left(\log x\over x\right)+\mathcal O\left(\frac1n\right) \\
&=\log2-\int_{N/2}^N\left({1-\log x\over x}\right)\mathrm dx+\mathcal O\left(\log N\over N\right) \\
&=\int_{N/2}^N{\log x\over x}\mathrm dx+\mathcal O\left(\log N\over N\right) \\
&=\frac12[\log^2N-\log^2(N/2)]+\mathcal O\left(\log N\over N\right) \\
&=\frac12[\log N+\log(N/2)][\log N-\log(N/2)]+\mathcal O\left(\log N\over N\right) \\
&=\frac12\log2[2\log N-\log2]+\mathcal O\left(\log N\over N\right) \\
&=\log2\log N-\frac12\log^22+\mathcal O\left(\log N\over N\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, employing this obtained identity and the asymptotic formula for harmonic series yields:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\le N}{(-1)^n\log n\over n}
&=\log2(\log N+\gamma)-\log2\log N+\frac12\log^22+\mathcal O\left(\log N\over N\right) \\
&=\gamma\log2+\frac12\log^22+\mathcal O\left(\log N\over N\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, take the limit $N\to\infty$ on both side gives

$$
\sum_{n\ge1}{(-1)^n\log n\over n}=\gamma\log2+\frac12\log^22
$$