# The value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\log n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to compute the following convergent series? or some hint!
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\log n}{n}.$$
The Wolfram MATHEMATICA9.0 gives the result is $1/2(\log 2)^2-\gamma\log 2$,
where $\gamma$ is tha Euler constant!

Comment: Do you want to show that the series is convergent? Or simply writing out the series expansion?

Comment: @Riemann Are you sure that it's possible?

Comment: do you wish to check if it is divergent\convergent? hint: use Leibniz test for alternating series.

Comment: of course this series is convergent, what I want is its sum!

Comment: check with matlab! I think you can't really know what the sum is. the more you compute the more accurate your sum is but I don't think it is possible otherwise.

Comment: Look here for some hints -> https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100894/254075.  Start with the Dirichlet eta  function $\eta(s):=\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$ which is very close to the Riemann zeta function.  Then use the Laurent series of the zeta function to help evaluate the derivative of the eta function  at $s=1$

Comment: @sharding4 I've posted a solution that evaluates the sum directly using the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula.

Comment: Another chance is to represent $\log(n)$ as an integral through Frullani's theorem, exploit the Taylor series of $-\log(1-x)$ and recognize/prove a well-known integral representation for $\gamma$.

Comment: @Riemann for a alternative series to converging a finite specific value we need the absolute convergence, here the absolute sum does not seem to be converging. (**Rearrangements**)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3297565/269624) for the integral expression of the series

Answer (score 12):

We can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{2N}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\log(n)}{n}&=\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{\log(n)}{n}-2\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log(2n)}{2n}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac{\log(n)}{n}-\log(2)\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n
\end{align}$$

Using the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=}^{2N}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\log(n)}{n}&=\int_{N+1}^{2N}\frac{\log(x)}{x}\,dx-\log(2)\,H_n+O\left(\frac{\log(N)}{N}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12\log^2(2N)-\frac12\log^2(N+1)-\log(2)\log(N)-\log(2)\gamma+O\left(\frac{\log(N)}{N}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12 \log^2(2)-\log(2)\gamma+O\left(\frac{\log(N)}{N}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Taking the limit as $N\to \infty$ yields the coveted limit

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\log(n)}{n}=\frac12\log^2(2)-\log(2)\gamma$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\,{\ln\pars{n} \over n}:\
> {\large ?}}$.

Hereafter, I'll use
[well known identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) which are related to the *Riemann Zeta Function*:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\,{\ln\pars{n} \over n} =
\left.\partiald{}{\mu}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over n^{1 - \mu}}
\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{+}} =
\left.\partiald{\bracks{\pars{1 - 2^{\mu}}\zeta\pars{1 - \mu}}}{\mu}\,
\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{+}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\partiald{}{\mu}
\braces{\bracks{-\ln\pars{2}\mu - {1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}\,\mu^{2} +
\,\mrm{O}\pars{\mu^{3}}}\bracks{-\,{1 \over \mu} + \gamma + \,\mrm{O}\pars{\mu^{1}}}}_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{+}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\partiald{}{\mu}\braces{\ln\pars{2} +
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2} - \gamma\ln\pars{2}}\mu + \,\mrm{O}\pars{\mu^{2}}}_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{+}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2} - \gamma\ln\pars{2}}
\end{align}