# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{e^x+1}$

Tags: integration, number-theory, riemann-zeta

I'm interested in evaluating the integral of

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{e^x+1}\ $$

TLDR: How do you evaluate $ \eta'(1) $?

I found and adapted this integral from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CM-6N5wWdmg&t=408s), unfortunately, they didn't fully evaluate the integral and I'm interested in the result.

This question is similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100321/int-0-infty-frac-log-xex1-dx-frac12-log-22-how-to), but my question goes more in-depth on the way that I tried to evaluate this integral.

This was solved by @J.G. in the answers, and by @Zacky in the comments.

I'll run through what I did and what the video did to evaluate the integral

$$ I =\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{e^x+1}$$

Multiplying by $ \frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}}\ $ results in

$$ = \int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}\ln(x)}{e^{-x}+1} $$

Expanding the denominator into a geometric sum results in

$$ = \int_0^\infty\ e^{-x}\ln(x)\sum_{k\ge0}{-e^{-x^k}} $$

Interchanging our signs of integration of summation and simplifying results in

$$ \sum_{k \ge 0}(-1)^k \int_0^\infty\ e^{-x(k+1)}\ln(x) $$

Substituting $ x(k+1) = t $ and $ dx = \frac{dt}{k+1} $ results in

$$ \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \int_0^\infty e^{-t}\ln(\frac t{k+1})\frac{dt}{k+1} $$

Expanded and simplified you get

$$ \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} (\int_0^\infty \ln(t)e^{-t}dt - \ln(k+1)\int_0^\infty e^{-t}dt) $$

Once again simplified we can see that our first integral is the $ \mathcal L\{\ln(t)\} $ at $s = 1$ and our second integral is $\Gamma(1)$ in total this results in.

Where $ \mathcal L $ is the Laplace transform and $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.

$$ \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}(\mathcal L\{\ln(t)\}-\ln(k+1)\Gamma(1)) $$

This then simplifies to

$$ \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}(-\gamma-\ln(k+1)) $$

With $ \gamma $ being the euler-mascheroni constant

Increasing our lower bound on our summation we get

$$ \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k(-\gamma-\ln(k)) $$

Realizing that the Dirichlet Eta function is defined as

$$ \eta(s) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^s} $$

We can then see that our equation is

$$ \eta(1)(-\gamma-\ln(k)) $$

Knowing that $ \eta(1) = \ln(2) $ we can then distribute our eta to get

$$ -\gamma\ln(2)-\ln(k)\eta(1) $$

Which is

$$ -\gamma\ln(2) - \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k\ln(k) $$

Taking the derivative of the eta function we can see that this is

$$ -\gamma\ln(2)+\eta'(1) $$

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) $ \eta'(1) $ is equal to $ \gamma\ln(2)-\frac{\ln(2)^2}2$

Meaning that our integral $I$ will evaluate to

$$ I = -\frac{\ln(2)^2}2$$

But how can we evaluate $ \eta'(1) $ without encountering the pole at $s = 1$ of the Zeta function?

Are there any other interesting ways to evaluate this integral not using the eta function?

Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: @AliShather Wouldn't that still not avoid the pole at $ s = 1 $ of the Zeta function? Is there some type of way to manipulate the Zeta function to get a value at $ s = 1 $?

Comment: @AliShather From what I've seen on Wikipedia and on Desmos I does seem to converge, but I just don't know how to evaluate it to get the value desired.

Comment: I'm not sure what is different than what you're asking. Anyway here's more: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895658/how-to-evaluate-a-certain-definite-integral-int-0-infty-frac-logxe, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100871/equality-with-euler-mascheroni-constant. I would recommend this answer though: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2586460/515527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $s\approx1$, $\zeta(s)\approx\frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma$ and $\zeta^\prime(s)\approx\frac{-1}{(s-1)^2}$, so$$\begin{align}\eta^\prime(s)&=2^{1-s}\ln2\cdot\zeta(s)+(1-2^{1-s})\zeta^\prime(s)\\&\approx(1+(1-s)\ln 2)\ln2\left(\frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma\right)-\frac{\ln 2}{s-1}+\frac12\ln^22\\&=\gamma\ln 2-\frac12\ln^22.\end{align}$$Note we only need to expand $2^{1-s}$ to $O(1-s)^2$ viz.$$2^{1-s}=1+(1-s)\ln 2+\frac12(1-s)^2\ln^22+o((1-s)^2)$$in the $\zeta^\prime$ term.

Comment: Is there a more rigorous definition other than $ s\approx1 $? What does the $ O(1-s)^2 $ mean? I have never seen this notation before.

Comment: @DarinClark See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinitesimal_asymptotics). I could have written$$=(1+(1-s)\ln2+O((1-s)^2))\ln2\left(\frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma+O(s-1)\right)-\frac{\ln 2}{s-1}+\frac12\ln^22+O(s-1)$$to avoid using $\approx$.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you, solved!