# a proof for the following Gamma function inequality

Tags: inequality, special-functions, gamma-function

Could you please provide or point me to a proof of inequality 5.6.8 found [at this site](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6)? That is,

$\left|\frac{\Gamma(z+a)}{\Gamma(z+b)}\right| \leq \frac{1}{|z|^{b-a}}$

for $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, and $a≥0, b≥a+1, Re(z)>0$.

Comment: At that link it has additional assumptions which you left out: $a \ge 0$, $b \ge a + 1$, $\text{Re}(z) > 0$.

Comment: The (i) link to the right of the inequality gives a reference to Paris and Kaminski (2001): http://dlmf.nist.gov/bib/P#bib1827

Comment: Also you got the left side wrong: it should be 
$\left| \dfrac{\Gamma(z+a)}{\Gamma(z+b)}\right|$

Comment: Ah thanks for that!

Comment: The book is available at [Google Books](http://books.google.de/books?id=LtOfHnClUSEC&lpg=PP1&dq=paris%20kaminski&hl=de&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q=paris%20kaminski&f=false), but p. 34, to which the citation points, isn't shown (for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to joriki's link to Google Books, here is the passage in question.

[image]

[image]

R. B. Paris and D. Kaminski, *Asymptotics and Mellin-Barnes Integrals*, pp. 33-34.

Answer (score 2):

For real $x>0$, the strict log-convexity of $\Gamma$ (see the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101007/)) implies that for $a\ge0$, $b\ge1$ and $b\ge a$,
$$
\frac{\log\Gamma(x+1)-\log\Gamma(x)}{1}\le\frac{\log\Gamma(x+b)-\log\Gamma(x+a)}{b-a}\tag{1}
$$
Which translates to
$$
\frac{\Gamma(x+a)}{\Gamma(x+b)}\le\frac{1}{x^{b-a}}\tag{2}
$$
Simpler, but not as general.

Comment: Thanks - I think this is useful to have as well.