# differentiate log Gamma function

Tags: derivatives, gamma-function

I am working with the log of negative binomial distribution $NegBin(r,p)$. I need to differentiate the following with respect to $r$ such that at the end, I am NOT left with $r$ in factorial form.

$$\frac{d \;log( \Gamma(x + r) )}{dr} = \;\; ?$$

I read about digamma function, but I have $x+r$ within the bracket in my case. Can anyone show me how this can be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/300574),
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(\Gamma(x))=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+x-1}\right)
$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

It is also mentioned there, that when $x$ is a positive integer,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+x-1}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{x-1}\frac1k=H_{x-1}
$$
where $H_n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ [Harmonic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

---

Since you ask about a slightly different form, we simply apply the chain rule:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r}\log(\Gamma(x+r))=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+x+r-1}\right)
$$

Comment: Hi, in my question, I have $x+r$ instead of just $x$. How can I deal with that as well ? And I am differentiating w.r.t $r$

Comment: To use $x+r$ and differentiate with respect to $r$ ... chain rule

Comment: Thanks. I just want to confirm that I have got the correct answer.