# L'Hopital's Rule, Factorials, and Derivatives

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, factorial

I have the following limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^n}{n!}$. Now if I try to solve this using this using L'hopital's rule, I won't be able to since I can't take the derivative of $n!$.

My question is why can't I take the derivative? Generally speaking, why can't I take the direct derivative of a factorial? I've seen other questions, but I just want a more simple answer (for someone at the Calculus 1 or 2 level).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps this might help:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300526/derivative-of-a-factorial

Comment: @SherlockHolmes Thank you, I saw that question as I was searching. I read about the Gamma function, but I don't fully understand. I think it's because I don't fully understand how factorials and derivatives work (or don't work)

Comment: The comment above is about as good as you can hope for.  Derivatives are a tool from calculus, for a derivative to exist the function must (at least) be continuous (over $\mathbb{R}$); because the factorial function is define over $\mathbb{N}$ we need a sensible way to define the notion of a derivative via a good extension to $\mathbb{R}$, the gamma function is just that.

Comment: @Squirtle So the factorial function as we know it (defined over ℕ) is not continuous over ℝ?

Comment: Of course it is not continuous over $\mathbb{R}$, because its not defined for non-integer values.  Often physicists (and some mathematicians) will talk about defining things like $(\frac{1}{2})!$ but in fact this is abuse of notation and what they are really talking about is the gamma function as it acts on rationals (in this case $0.5$).

Comment: @Squirtle Thank you! Yes, that's exactly what confused me!

Comment: Sorry its $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so it's $\Gamma(1.5)=(\frac{1}{2})!$ (when we abuse notation).  In the above comment I abused the abused notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A derivative of the factorial function exists if you can define factorials of non-integers is a smooth way, and that can be done by using the fact that $n!=\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x}\,dx$.  But actually writing down a good expression for the derivative is another matter.

However, the limit is easy to show to be $0$.  Think of what happens when $n$, on its way up to $\infty$, goes from $1000$ to $1001$, and observe that the pattern continues: The numerator gets multiplied by $e$, making it less than $3$ times as big, but the denominator gets multiplied by $1001$, so the whole thing gets multiplied by something smaller than $3/1001$.  And at the next step, from $1001$ to $1002$, and all later steps, it gets multiplied by something even smaller.  And this keeps happening over and over every time $n$ increases by $1$.

So the fraction must approach $0$.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!