# Gamma function and logarithms question

Tags: gamma-function

I'm trying to find
$$
\int_0^\infty\ln(x)\,x^2e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Could anyone help explain this to me? I'm also interested in changing the $e^{-x}$ to an $e^{-ax}$. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is most easily handled using the Gamma function
$$
\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
$$
Note that if we take the derivative, we get
$$
\Gamma'(x)=\int_0^\infty\log(t)\,t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
$$
So your question is asking for $\Gamma'(3)$.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/300574), it is shown that
$$
\Gamma'(n+1)=n!\,(-\gamma+H_n)\tag{3}
$$
Where $H_n$ is a [Harmonic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

---

Note that with the change of variables $t\mapsto at$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(x)
&=\int_0^\infty\log(at)\,(at)^{x-1}e^{-at}\,\mathrm{d}at\\
&=a^x\int_0^\infty(\log(a)+\log(t))\,t^{x-1}e^{-at}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Using the fact that $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ and $(1)$-$(4)$, it is not difficult to compute
$$
\int_0^\infty\log(t)\,t^{x-1}e^{-at}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{5}
$$