# How to compute $\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\ln(x)} dx = \ln(2)$? and $\int_0^\infty \ln(t) e^{-t} dt $?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\ln(x)} dx = \ln(2)$

First  i try 
$\ln(x)=t$ so that $\frac{1}{x} dx =dt$ then integral becomes 
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{e^t-1}{t} (e^t dt)
= - \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}-1}{t} e^{-t} dt
= -\int_0^{\infty} (t^{-1} e^{-2t} - t^{-1} e^{-t})dt \\
&
= - \ln(t) e^{-2t} |_{0, \infty} - 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(t) e^{-2t}dt + \ln(t) e^{-t}|_{0, \infty} + \int_0^{\infty} \ln(t) e^{-t} dt
\end{align}
This substitution reproduce the integral form of 
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \ln(t) e^{-t} dt
\end{align}

hmm.

I want to know other kinds of evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{\ln(x)} dx = \ln(2)$ 
and evaluating of $\int_0^\infty \ln(t) e^{-t} dt$.

Comment: Doesn't $\displaystyle{-\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(t) e^{-2t}d(2t)= -\int_{0}^{\infty} (\ln(2t)-\ln 2) e^{-2t}d(2t)}$ and $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(t) e^{-t}dt}$ cancel to make $\ln 2$ ?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin, Oh Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I(b) = \int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{x^b - 1}{\ln x} dx$. Then :
\begin{align}
I'(b) &= \int\limits_0^1  \dfrac{\partial }{\partial b}\dfrac{x^b - 1}{\ln x} dx\\
&=\int\limits_0^1  x^b dx\\
&= \dfrac{1}{b+1}
\end{align}
Hence :
$$I(b) = \ln (b+1) + C$$ with $C\in \mathbb{R}.$ To find $C$ note that $I(0) = 0$ which implies $C= 0$. So $I(1) = \ln(2)$.
To handle the second integral note that :
$$\Gamma (x)= \int\limits_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt,\qquad \Gamma' (x)= \int\limits_0^\infty  t^{x-1}e^{-t}\ln tdt$$
As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300526/derivative-of-a-factorial/300574#300574), since $\Gamma$ is log-convex one has :
$$\dfrac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)} = -\gamma + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k} - \dfrac{1}{k+x-1}.$$
So $$\int\limits_0^\infty \log(t) e^{-t} dt = \Gamma'(1) = -\gamma$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Thanks for detailed procedure!  I think i am well aware of gamma function and digamma function, but can not think of using here in this integral!. Your answer enlarge my world!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, the best way of simplifying something is by making it more complicated. :-$)$

**Hint:** Evaluate $I(k)=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{x^k-1}{\ln x}~dx$ by differentiating under the integral sign with regards to *k*.

Comment: The second integral has already been evaluated [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/902574/2).

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps me a lot!