# How can I differentiate this function (A continuous Poisson distribution)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$y=\frac{m^x e^{-m}}{x!}$$
Where $m\in\mathbb{R}^+$. How can I differentiate it? I want to find the maximum THROUGH CALCULUS.

Comment: what is the variable?

Comment: check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300526/derivative-of-a-factorial

Comment: if this corresponds to the probabilities $\Bbb P(X=x)$ where $X$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $m$, then the expression is only defined for $x\in \Bbb N$, so differentiation won't help you finding the maximum.