# Analytically finding the value of $n$ for which $n \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{60-k}{60}$ is maximized

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graphing-functions, products

I was solving a problem where I needed to find the value of $n\in [0,60] \cap \mathbb N$ for which $$f(n)=n \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{60-k}{60}$$ is maximized.

Somewhat irresponsibly, I computed the value of the expression for $n=1,2,...,9$, saw that it decreases after $n=8$ and assumed that $n=8$ gives the maximum value.

Not only does this assume that the value of $f$ "increases then decreases," allowing only one candidate for a maximum, but it also doesn't shed any light on how I would solve the question or graph the function in the general case.

Therefore, I have 3 questions:

(1) How would I find the maximum (or maxima, if unsure of how many extrema there would be) analytically?

(2) Is it trivial to show that $f$ "increases then decreases"?

(3)  How might I sketch $f$ (by hand) ?

Can the answers for the above questions be generalized for the general case function $g(n)=n \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\alpha-k}{\alpha}$ for $n\in [0,\alpha] \cap \mathbb N$?

Comment: Probably the best way to do it analitically is using the Gamma function to express the factorial, and then graph the continuous function

Comment: @TiwaAina [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300526/derivative-of-a-factorial) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial answer, points (1) and (2)**.
$$g(n+1)=(n+1)\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\alpha-k}{\alpha}=
n\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\alpha-k}{\alpha} + \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\alpha-k}{\alpha}=\\
g(n)\frac{\alpha-n}{\alpha}+\frac{g(n)}{n}\frac{\alpha-n}{\alpha}=\\
g(n)\frac{\alpha-n}{\alpha}\frac{n+1}{n}$$
To have a growth, we ask for
$$\frac{\alpha-n}{\alpha}\frac{n+1}{n}\geq1 \tag{1}$$
because that will make $\color{red}{g(n+1)\geq g(n)}$. This happens for:
$$(\alpha-n)(n+1)\geq \alpha n \Leftrightarrow \\
\alpha n+ \alpha - n^2 -n \geq \alpha n \Leftrightarrow\\
n^2 +n - \alpha \leq 0$$
or
$$n \leq \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2} \tag{2}$$
As a result, the growth finishes at around $\left \lfloor  \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2} \right \rfloor$ or $\left \lfloor  \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2} \right \rfloor +1$. For $n >\left \lfloor  \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2} \right \rfloor +1$ we have
$$\frac{\alpha-n}{\alpha}\frac{n+1}{n}<1 \tag{3}$$
which means $\color{red}{g(n+1)<g(n)}$ and the sequence will start decreasing, thus the maximum is reached at around $\left \lfloor  \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2} \right \rfloor$ or $\left \lfloor  \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2} \right \rfloor +1$

For $\alpha=60$ we have, from $(2)$, that $n\approx 7$ or $8$, which can be seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5Bn%2B1%5D%3Da%5Bn%5D%20*%20(60-n)%2F60%20*%20(n%2B1)%2Fn,%20a%5B1%5D%3D1). For $\alpha=160 \Rightarrow n\approx 12$ or $13$

Comment: Why "$\left \lfloor  \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2} \right \rfloor$ or $\left \lfloor  \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2} \right \rfloor +1$" instead of $\left \lceil \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}{2} \right \rceil $ ?

Comment: Because it's not 100% accurate, for $\alpha=60$, $(2)$ gives $n\approx7.26$, flooring is $7$, but maximum is achieved at $8$. For  $\alpha=160$, $(2)$ gives $n\approx 12.159$ , flooring is $12$ and maximum is achieved at $12$.

Comment: But in both of those cases, doesn't ceiling do the job?

Comment: What I meant to write is, I am not sure if ceiling always takes over flooring.