# How to show that $\frac{\sqrt{n-1}\Gamma((n-1)/2)}{\sqrt{2}\Gamma(n/2)}>1$.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $$\frac{\sqrt{n-1}\Gamma((n-1)/2)}{\sqrt{2}\Gamma(n/2)}>1$$

I tried to solve it using Taylor series expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101007), it is shown that $\Gamma(x)$ is log-convex. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma\left(\frac n2\right)
&\le\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)^{1/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)^{1/2}\\[6pt]
&=\sqrt{\frac{n-1}2}\ \Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)
\end{align}
$$
since $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$.

---

**Implication of Log-Convexity**

A log-convex function is a function whose logarithm is convex. Thus, if $f$ is log-convex, we have
$$
\log\circ f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)\le\frac{\log\circ f(x)+\log\circ f(y)}2
$$
removing the $\log$s by applying $\exp$, which is monotonically increasing, we get
$$
f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)\le f(x)^{1/2}f(y)^{1/2}
$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Thanks, I get what a log-convex function is. Unfortunately, I don't understand how the fact that \Gamma(x) is log-convex yields to the inequality above. Could you please explain it to me a little bit?

Comment: @Filip: I've added a section on log-convexity. Let me know if there is still confusion.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot!