# Prove $\lim\limits_{r \to \infty} r-\frac{\sqrt{r}}{e^{r}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma{(n+3/2)}r^n}{(n!)^2}=1/4$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, gamma-function, bessel-functions

This is a follow-up question for the one described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922060/evaluate-lim-limits-r-to-infty-frac-sqrtrer-sum-n-0-infty).

> Evaluate 
>   $$\lim\limits_{r \to \infty} r-\frac{\sqrt{r}}{e^{r}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma{(n+3/2)}r^n}{(n!)^2}=1/4$$

There is a related but not complete answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922060/evaluate-lim-limits-r-to-infty-frac-sqrtrer-sum-n-0-infty). But, I was not sure how to complete it. Also, one might write $\frac{\sqrt{r}}{e^{r}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma{(n+3/2)}r^n}{(n!)^2}$ in terms of Bessel Functions and then use the expansion of the Bessel Functions.

Comment: I suppose typo since the result should be $\color{red}{-}\frac 14$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for your comment. Can you please expand on your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that, in the previous post, skbmoore's answer gives the key
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma{(n+3/2)}\,r^n}{(n!)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  e^{r/2} \left((r+1) I_0\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)+r
   I_1\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)\right)$$
$$y= r-\frac{\sqrt{r}}{e^{r}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma{(n+3/2)}r^n}{(n!)^2}=r-\frac{\sqrt{\pi r}}{2}  e^{-r/2}  \left((r+1)
   I_0\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)+r I_1\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)\right)$$

Now, using equation [$9.7.1$ in page $377$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_377.htm) of the *Handbook of Mathematical Functions* by Abramowitz and Stegun we have, for large values of $z$
$$I_0(z)\sim \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2 \pi z } }\left(1+\frac{1}{8 z}+\frac{9}{128 z^2}+\frac{75}{1024
   z^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^4}\right)\right)$$
$$I_1(z)\sim \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2 \pi z } }\left(1-\frac{3}{8 z}-\frac{15}{128 z^2}-\frac{105}{1024
   z^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^4}\right)\right)$$ which lead to 
$$y=-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{32 r}-\frac{3}{128 r^2}-\frac{75}{256
   r^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{r^4}\right)$$

Consider $r=10$ : the exact value would be $y\approx -0.253411$ while the above expansion leads to $-\frac{12987}{51200}\approx -0.253652$.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you are right!

Comment: I approve this message

Comment: @skbmoore. You made it in fact (I upvoted your answer). I just gave more about the expansions; that's it ! Cheers.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici.  Thanks for the upvote.  I still don't know what is 'too much help' is for problems.

Comment: Thanks. How do you derive the first equation?

Comment: @Susan_Math123. When you put a question to user **xxx**, start your text with **@xxx** in order the user be notified. I do not understand your question : what do you mean by *the first equation* ?

Comment: OK. I meant this: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma{(n+3/2)}\,r^n}{(n!)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  e^{r/2} \left((r+1) I_0\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)+r
   I_1\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)\right)$