# Modified Bessel function of order 0 and 1 question

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, bessel-functions

@skbmoore

> Prove that 
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma{(n+3/2)}\,r^n}{(n!)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  e^{r/2} \left((r+1) I_0\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)+r
>    I_1\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)\right)$$

This is a follow-up question of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922060/evaluate-lim-limits-r-to-infty-frac-sqrtrer-sum-n-0-infty).

I have been trying to verify this, but I only did not know how to. I searched for the expansion of $I_0$ and $I_1$ something with an exponential function, but nothing found. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved in a CAS, but to make it interesting, let's do most of the work ourselves. By properties of the gamma function
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+3/2)}{n!^2}r^n
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1/2)\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)} \frac{r^n}{n!^2} =\big(r\,\frac{d}{dr}+\frac{1}{2}\big)
\underbrace{ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{r^n}{n!}\,2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n}}_{:=S(r)}$$
It is assumed the OP can do the derivatives and algebra. My part of the derivation is through when I can show
$$ (*) \quad S(r) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{r^n}{n!}\,2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n} = e^{r/2}\,I_0(r/2)$$ where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function.  This can probably be shown by a (Cauchy) power series product, but I chose to reduce it to the well-known integral relationship 
$$ I_0(x)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \exp{\big(-x\,\cos(t)\big)} dt$$
Use another well-known relationship (I believe derivable from a trig substitution into the beta integral) for the central binomials.

$$ \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2}\! \sin^{2n}(t) \,dt = 2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n}$$

Insert this into the definition for $S(r)$ and interchange $\sum$ and $\int.$  The sum is simply the exponential and the expression so obtained is
$$S(r)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \exp{\big( r\,\sin^2(t)\,\big)} dt=
\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \exp{\big(\frac{r}{2}\,(1-\cos(2t))\,\big)} dt
 $$
by a trigonometric identity. Finally, by rescaling the integral
$$S(r)=e^{r/2} \, \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi}\exp{\big(\!-\frac{r}{2}\,\cos(t)\big)} dt$$ which completes the proof of (*).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please let me know what is CAS?

Comment: How about OP? can you tell me what that is?

Comment: OP=original proposer, CAS=computer-aided symbolics (I think; I'm sort of new myself) which I take to be Mathematica (which I use) or Maple

Comment: Thanks. So, you give Mathematica a series and it writes it with respect to well-known functions like $I_0$ and $I_1$?

Comment: Interchanging the $\int$ and $\sum$ requires monotone convergence theore which is true since the terms under the sum are positive?