# Weierstrass Factorization theorem on the Reciprocal Gamma Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, gamma-function, infinite-product

I am just a bit curious about the Weierstrass Factorization theorem on the Gamma function.

The Weierstrass Factorization theorem says this:

> Let $f(z)$ be an entire function. Suppose that $f$ vanishes to order $m, m \geq 0$. Let ${a_n}$ be the other zeros of $f$, listed with multiplicities. Then there is an entire function, $g(z)$ such that
>   $$f(z) = z^m e^{g(z)} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} E_{n-1}\left(\frac{z}{a_n}\right).$$

From the reciprocal Gamma function, by the Weierstrass factorization theorem, they came up with this:

$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} = ze^{\gamma*z}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1 + \frac{z}{n}\right)e^{-z/n}.
$$

Now how did they compute the Weierstrass Elementary Factors? I know the definition of the factors. I have looked this function and it says it has simple zeros at $0$ and at all negative integers. I am just confused how they computed the elementary factors on this function. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: It is known that all elementary factors can be taken to be $e^{z/r}$ if the function grows at most like $e^{|z|^\alpha}$ for $\alpha<2$. Stirling's approximation to $\Gamma(z)$ establishes such a bound for $\alpha=1+\varepsilon$.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean.

Comment: Seems like you need Hadamard’s factorization theorem.

Comment: Are you assuming $1/\Gamma(z)$ is entire ? Its zeros are known to be at negative integers. Estimating its growth isn't difficult thus obtaining the condition for applying Weierstrass factorization.

Answer (score 1):

The convexity of $\log(\Gamma(x))$ says that for $x\in[0,1]$,
$$
\Gamma(n)\,(n-1+x)^x\le\Gamma(n+x)\le\Gamma(n)\,n^x
$$
and the inequalities are reversed for $x\not\in[0,1]$. Note that this is exact for $x\in\{0,1\}$. In any case, 
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)!\,n^x}{\Gamma(n+x)}\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)!\,n^x}{\Gamma(x)\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+x)}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k\sim\gamma+\log(n)$, we get $n^x=e^{x\log(n)}\sim e^{-\gamma x}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{x/k}$
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(x)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)!\,n^x}{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+x)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^x}x\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k}{k+x}\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{-\gamma x}}x\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{e^{x/k}}{1+x/k}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{e^{-\gamma x}}x\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{x/k}}{1+x/k}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @reuns: Other than log-convexity (which is mentioned), I am only using the usual $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ and $\Gamma(1)=1$.

Comment: So $\Gamma(x+1) = x \Gamma(x)$ plus $\log$-convexity on $x > 0$ implies the Weierstrass product for $x > 0$ and by analytic continuation it stays true for $\Gamma(z), z\in \Bbb{C}$. The $\log$-convexity [follows](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Log_of_Gamma_Function_is_Convex_on_Positive_Reals#Proof_2) from Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: If we *define* $\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t$, then the log-convexity follows from Cauchy-Schwarz or Jensen's Inequality, as shown at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101007). However, the [Bohr-Mollerup Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) guarantees that we get the same $\Gamma(x)$ assuming the standard recurrence and log-convexity.