# An improper integral related to logarithm function

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I was interested in solving for $\eta'(1)$ where $\eta(s)$ is Dirichlet eta function, and I am now able to expand it like this based on the fact that $\displaystyle\Gamma(s)\eta(s)=\int_0^\infty{t^{s-1}\over e^t+1}\mathrm{d}t$:

$$
\eta'(1)=\gamma\ln(2)+\int_0^\infty{\ln(t)\over e^t+1}\mathrm{d}t
$$

I would like to evaluate the remaining integral via contour integration, and I have failed to find a proper contour for it (I have tried half circle and branch cuts but failed), so could anybody in MSE provide me some hints for finding the integral.

NOTE: In fact, I have read [$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\log (x)}{e^x+1} \, dx = -\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(2)$ How to show?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100321) before asking this question. Instead of series method, I am looking for an approach that solves this integral by contour integration, so I wonder if anybody could come up some contours that solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\log (x)}{e^x+1} \, dx = -\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(2)$ How to show?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100321/int-0-infty-frac-log-xex1-dx-frac12-log-22-how-to)

Comment: @mrtaurho I have read that thread before asking this question; you can see more in my edited question

Comment: IMO, if a real approach is possible *and* easier than using contour integration you should always go for the first; anyway, I think you edit made it even clearer that you are especially looking for a complex-analytics solution.