# Convergence\Divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)} {2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Prove convergence\divergence of the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac {1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)} {2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}$$

Here is what I have at the moment:

**Method I**

My first way uses a result that is related to **[Wallis product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product)** that we'll denote by $W_{n}$.  Also,
we  may denote $\dfrac {1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)} {2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}$ by $P_{n}$. Having noted these and taking a large
value of $n$
we get:
$$(P_{n})^2 =\frac{1}{W_{n} \cdot (2n+1)}\approx\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot \frac{1}{2n+1}$$
$$P_{n}\approx \sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$

Further we have that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot \frac{n}{\sqrt{2n+1}} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P_{n}$$ 
that obviously shows us that the series diverges.

**Method II**

The second way is to resort to the powerful **[Kummer's Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KummersTest.html)** and firstly proceed with the ratio test:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{P_{n+1}}{P_{n}}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}=1$$
and according to the result, the ratio test is inconclusive.

Now, we apply Kummer's test and get:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{P_{n}}{P_{n+1}}n-(n+1)=\lim_{n\to\infty} -\frac{n+1}{2n+1}=-\frac{1}{2} \le 0$$
Since 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \longrightarrow \infty$$
our series diverges and we're done.

On the site I've also found  [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118383/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-left-dfrac-1-cdot3-cdots-2n-1?rq=1) with answers that can be applied for my question. 
Since I've already have some answers for my question you may regard it as a recreational one and if you have a nice proof to share I'd be glad to receive it. I like this question very much and want to make up a collection with nice proofs for it. Thanks.

Comment: Aryabhata's estimate $\dfrac {1\cdot 3\cdots (2n-1)} {2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n}}$ gives the answer by the $p$-test (as in my answer below).

Comment: You can also use Raabe's test, $lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)$ if your result $P>1$ then the series is convergent, $P<1$ the series is divergent, and if $P=1$ then the test is inconclusive.

In solving the limit, you are almost assuredly going to have to use L'Hospital rule

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html

Comment: @robjohn: when I firstly saw that inequality I wondered where it came from. I don't remember exactly, but it's possible that I met it before, maybe in my first year in high school when studying the induction chapter. This inequality form is really nice.

Comment: @Joseph Skelton: yeah, Raabe's test is also useful here.

Comment: It seems that Gauss test may also work nice.

Comment: Demonstrate with logs --> Taylor?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since 
$$ \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n)} \ge \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n-2)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n)} = \frac1{2n} $$
the series diverges by comparison to the Harmonic series.

Comment: really awesome! (+1)

Comment: You beat me! Good job.

Comment: @Morgan Sherman: it's nice to see that such a small trick brings you to the result so fast. :-)

Comment: The estimate is simple and loose, but it gets the job done (+1).

Answer (score 8):

$$
\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!^2}\tag{1}
$$
Using Stirling's Formula, we get that
$$
\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!^2}\sim\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}\tag{2}
$$
By the $p$-test,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^p}\tag{3}
$$
diverges for $p\le1$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}\tag{4}
$$
diverges.

**Derivation of (1):**

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}
&=\frac{1\cdot\color{#C00000}{2}\cdot3\cdot\color{#C00000}{4}\cdot5\cdot\color{#C00000}{6}\cdots(2n-1)\cdot\color{#C00000}{(2n)}}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)\color{#C00000}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}}\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{(2^nn!)^2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: nice! (+1) Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused, how do you get (1)?

Comment: $$\eqalign{
  \frac{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)!!}}{{\left( {2n} \right)!!}} = \frac{{\left( {2n} \right)!!\left( {2n - 1} \right)!!}}{{\left( {2n} \right)!!\left( {2n} \right)!!}} &\cr 
   = \frac{{\left( {2n} \right)!}}{{\left( {{2^n}n!} \right)\left( {{2^n}n!} \right)}} &\cr 
   = \frac{{\left( {2n} \right)!}}{{{4^n}n{!^2}}} &\cr} $$

Comment: ah, ok. That makes much more sense now. I was unaware there was even a name for that product. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Thanks for that. I have just added a derivation to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As robjohn notes, $$
\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!^2} = \frac 1{4^n} \binom{2n}{n}
$$
Noting that $$(2n+1) \binom{2n}{n} > \sum_{i=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{i} = 4^n$$
As $\binom{2n}{n}$ is the largest binomial coefficient.

Therefore, $$\frac 1{4^n} \binom{2n}{n} > \frac{1}{2n+1},$$ and hence the series diverges, by the comparison test.

Comment: you mean $4^n$ on the 4th row, right?

Comment: Yeah, edited. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your nice solution! (+1)