# Proving that Σ(2n)!!/(2n+1)!! diverges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

How does one prove that Σ(2n)!!/(2n+1)!! diverges? The ratio test is inconclusive and I don't know how to use the comparison test and the limit comparison test in the situation.

Edit: I found an answer to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183768/convergence-divergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-1-cdot-3-cdots-2n-1?rq=1).

Comment: What is your definition of double factorial?

Comment: Do you know Raabe's test?

Comment: (2n) = 2 · 4 · 6 ·...· 2n and (2n + 1) = 3 · 5 · 7 ·...· 2n + 1

Comment: No I haven't heard of Raabe's test but I'll look it up.

Comment: You could also work with Stirling's formula, converting double factorials into expressions with factorials isn't too hard.