# Exercise from Comtet's Advanced Combinatorics: prove $27\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }1/\binom{2n}{n}=9+2\pi \sqrt{3}$

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

In exercise 36 *Miscellaneous Taylor Coefficients using Bernoulli
numbers* on pages 88-89 of Louis Comtet's *[Advanced Combinatorics](https://books.google.pt/books?id=C0HPgWhEssYC&lpg=PP1&dq=Louis%20Comtet%20Advanced%20Combinatorics&hl=pt-PT&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, 1974,
one is asked to obtain the following explicit formula for the Bernoulli numbers:

$$B_{2n}=(-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{1+\left[ \varphi _{n}\right] }{2(2^{2n}-1)},$$

where

$$\varphi _{n}=\dfrac{2(2^{2n}-1)(2n)!}{2^{2n-1}\pi ^{2n}}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2n}}$$

(with $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 0}B_{n}\dfrac{t^{n}}{n!}=\dfrac{t}{e^{t}-1}$), and to prove, among other sums, that

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{\dbinom{2n}{n}}=\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{2\pi\sqrt{3}}{27}.\qquad (\ast )$$

Alfred van der Poorten wrote [here (section 10)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03028234): *seeing that*

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{2n}}{n^{2}\dbinom{2n}{n}}=2\arcsin^{2}\left( \dfrac{x}{2}\right) \qquad (\ast \ast )$$

(...) *formula* [ $(\ast )$ ] *become*[s] *quite accessible to proof*."

I am not able to show formula $(\ast \ast )$ neither how it can be used to
prove $(\ast )$.

---

**Question**: Could you provide (a) more detailed hint(s) on how and/or
different ways in which formula $(\ast )$ can be derived?

---

Added: For information the other sums are:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{n\dbinom{2n}{n}}=\dfrac{\pi \sqrt{3}}{9},\quad\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{n^{2}\dbinom{2n}{n}}=\dfrac{\pi ^{2}}{18},\quad\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{n^{4}\dbinom{2n}{n}}=\dfrac{17\pi ^{4}}{3240}.$$

Comment: you'll find several other related sums over at. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another one, which has been mentioned multiple times on this site (search for Wallis' product) is the following:

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n-1} x \ dx = \dfrac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n-2)}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)} \ \ n \gt 1$$

Now $$\displaystyle \dfrac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n-2)}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)} = \dfrac{2^{2n}}{2n{2n \choose n}} = \dfrac{2^{2n-1}}{n{2n \choose n}}$$

Thus

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/2} n\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{2}\right)^{2n-1} \ dx = \dfrac{1}{{2n \choose n}}$$

Now the sum can be found easily.

The formula by Alfred Van der Pooten can be proved using this approach too.

A proof of Wallis Product is given here: http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/pi/wallis.xhtml

For a (closely related) problem on this site using this, see here: [Summing the series $(-1)^k \frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!} a^{2k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/summing-the-series-1k-frac2k2k1-a2k1)

Comment: The link to `crypto.stanford.edu` seems to be broken...

Answer (score 11):

$$\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}} = (2n+1) \int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n dx$$

Sum these over $n$ to get the integral of a rational function.

Comment: BTW, where to find the proof of this formula for integral of $x^n(1-x)^n$?

Comment: @TCL: I give a probabilistic proof here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/beta-function-derivation

Comment: @TCL: it is a value of the Beta function (integral).

Answer (score 8):

I'm surprised no one has yet posted the generating function approach.  An excellent reference is Sprugnoli, "[Sums of Reciprocals of the Central Binomial Coefficients](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf)," *Integers*, Article A27, 2006.

He proves that the generating function of $4^n \binom{2n}{n}^{-1}$ is

$$Z(t) = \frac{1}{1-t} \sqrt{\frac{t}{1-t}} \arctan \sqrt{\frac{t}{1-t}} + \frac{1}{1-t}.$$
Substituting $t=1/4$ immediately yields $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n}^{-1} = \dfrac{4}{3}+\dfrac{2\pi\sqrt{3}}{27}.$$

He also derives generating functions for $\frac{4^n}{n} \binom{2n}{n}^{-1}$, $\frac{4^n}{n^2} \binom{2n}{n}^{-1}$, and several other similar expressions involving the reciprocals of the central binomial coefficients, which allows him to deduce *a few dozen* expressions for various finite and infinite sums involving $\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}$.  Again, it's an excellent reference.

Incidentally, in the introduction the author states that his motivation for writing the paper was the very exercise in Comtet that motivated this question.

Answer (score 4):

You want to get rid of the factor of $n^2$ in the denominator.  So differentiate with respect to $x$, that gets rid of one factor.  If you modify what you get you can differentiate again to get rid of the other.

Answer (score 2):

Just as additional information, the inverse of these binomial coefficients satisfy several wonderful identities. For example, on [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html) I saw the following amazing identity (valid for $k\ge 1$):

$$\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{1}{n^k \binom{2n}{n}} = \frac{1}{2}{}_{k+1}F_k(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{k+1}; \frac{3}{2}, \underbrace{2,\ldots,2}_{k-1}; \frac{1}{4}),$$

where ${}_{k+1}F_k$ is a generalized hypergeometric function.

How to derive the above result? I don't recall the answer immediately, but perhaps browsing [Zeilberger's website](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/) might be helpful.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the relation to the generalized hypergeometric function.

Comment: Unfortunately, as stated in the page you linked to, the hypergeometric formula is useful only for $k > 0$ ; remember also that ${}_1 F_0 (a;;z)$ takes only two arguments, and thus the formula in your answer certainly cannot apply.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that $k\ge 1$ is needed; fixed.

Comment: So the relation is applicable only to the other sums I added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some more useful info related to your first sum.

Recall that when summing $\sum_{n\ge 0} t_n$ we can use the idea of hypergeometrics, by computing the ratio $t_{n+1}/t_n$, and then reading-off from it the Hypergeometric function that solves the summation.

In your case, the ratio is
$$\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n} = \frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{(n+1/2)4},$$ so the sum over all $t_n$ ranging from $n\ge 0$ instead of $n\ge 1$ as you ask, is nothing but the hypergeometric function
$${}_2F_1(1, 1; \frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{4})$$

which may be verified using some of the ideas above to be equal to 
$$\frac{2}{27} \left(18+\sqrt{3} \pi \right)$$

Comment: How does this help?