# How can I compute this?(method)

Tags: statistics

$$\mu = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^{k}}{\displaystyle{2k+1 \choose k}}$$

The answer is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. But I don't know how to do it. Please show me the way! Thank you.

Comment: The answer should be $1+\pi/2$. If $k$ starts at $1$ instead, then you get just $\pi/2$

Comment: @BeaumontTaz Thank you! then, How can i compute this?!?

Comment: @user170141 What do you mean?!? I can't get it....

Comment: Hint: expand the binomial coefficient and do some canceling.

Comment: @user170141 I did some canceling and the result is.   sigma  (k+1)!/(2k+1)!!  . and from now on, how can I handle this? Thank you again.

Comment: @user175721, now [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77607/how-to-sum-this-series-for-pi-2-directly) question becomes relevant to you.

Comment: @BeaumontTaz boom.